# Extract Numeric Value from String Regex PHP

Tags: php, regex

I'm receiving an XML success string from a remote API.

The string is like so:

```
SAP: Your order (Reference ID: 725275) was accepted!
```

I'd like to find a fast and simple one line solution to just get the numeric portion of the reference id for database storage.

The number itself can be from 6 to 20 digits.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is perhaps as trivial as a regex could be.  Did you try anything at all?

Comment: I really hope no one answers this.

Comment: I looked through other answers but my understanding of regex is minimal. I just can't seem to get the hang of it.

Comment: `[0-9]\d` http://regexone.com/lesson/1

Comment: Your understanding of regex would _continue to remain minimal_ unless you __try anything__.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

It will match only reference id

```
/\b(\d{6,20})\b/
```

check [here](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/3Bu)

Comment: Thanks a lot.  When using `preg_match("/\b(\d{6,20})\b/", $input_line, $output_array);` It returns an array with 2 items. Is that correct?

Comment: Removing boundary condition returns you one array try this pattern /\d{6,20}/    $0 contains what you expect.

Comment: Accept answer if u got the solution..

Comment: Had to go with a different solution. Thanks for trying though.

Comment: HI @user3064914..Can you explain what is /\b representating ?explain it please ...i dont know much more about preg_match?

Comment: \b -> is boundary condition. With in // pattern is written for example /(pattern)/